# String containing Chinese character to ASCII

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding, ascii

This is my code, both of the two ways give the same output.

```
String description = "test string with 音樂";
byte[] b = description.getBytes("US-ASCII");

//first way
char[] result = new char[b.length];       
for ( int i = 0; i < b.length; i++ ) {
    result[i] = (char)b[i];
}
System.out.println(new String(result)); //output - test string with ??

//second way
System.out.println(new String(b, "UTF-8")); //output - test string with ??
```

I am using **Eclipse** and changed console output encoding to **US-ASCII** under **Run Configuration**

Is it possible to get it as US-ASCII encoding string?

Thanks adv!!!

Comment: So what's the output you want for "test string with 音樂"?

Comment: Well what are you trying to achieve? You do understand that ASCII simply doesn't have those characters, right?

Comment: @JonSkeet I am trying to convert it to ASCII represent string. Is it possible? In fact, I am newbie in unicode.

Comment: If you want Chinese characters, then the answer is "no". You should read up on ASCII: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to convert Chinese characters to US-ASCII because they are not contained in this character set.

US-ASCII knows only 128 different characters and some of them are even non-printing control characters.

Comment: So it is not possible if the string contain Chinese or French character?

Comment: no. The link provided by Jon Skeet shows all the possible characters.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to convert it to US-ASCII but,

If you just want Unicode escaped string then you can use apache common lang utility,

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;

...
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava("test string with \u97F3\u6A02"); 
 //gives result : test string with 音樂
StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava("test string with 音樂"); 
 //gives result : test string with \u97F3\u6A02
```